# How to remove the leaflet L.control.layers

Tags: leaflet

I'd like to remove the layers control from my map, but I just can't find the solution...I tried almost everything I found on the internet

This what i tried so far:

```
var layerscontrol = L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);
...
layerscontrol.removeFrom(map);
```

or

```
layerscontrol.remove(map);
```

or

```
map.removeControl(layerscontrol);
```

what have I done wrong?

Comment: *map.removeControl(layerscontrol);* is correct. It is most likely a scope issue: you might not be able to talk to your map variable from where you are trying to remove the control. Can you post your entire code or at least a larger part?

Comment: I set a function to remove the control, because I'd like to change the legend onclick...but on click, there appears a second control, so I have to remove the first one first...

Comment: //Layer Control 
  var baseLayers = {
   "OSM": osmBase,
   "OpenCycleMap": OpenCycleMap,
   "StamenWatercolor": StamenWatercolor,
   
   
  };
  
  var overlays = {};
  var layerscontrol = L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);
  
 function change_legend(){
    layerscontrol.removeFrom(map);
  overlays = {
   'CO2-Emission pro Kopf [t]': worldbankLayer,
   };
   L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map); 
 };

Comment: sorry that was the old one...instead of layerscontrol.removeFrom(map)

Comment: ...this one : 
 
map.removeControl(layerscontrol);

Comment: Your code works fine. Do you want to remove it and not have it back or do you want to immediately add a new layer control? Currently you are removing it but immediately adding a new one, so it looks like it is never being removed, but in reality it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are adding your control again, right after you remove it, which makes it appear like it is never removed, but in reality you are removing your control and adding a new one right after.

To fully remove it you need to omit the following line from your *change_legend* function:

```
 L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);
```

Here is the entire code:

```
var baseLayers = {
    "OSM": osmBase,
    "OpenCycleMap": OpenCycleMap,
    "StamenWatercolor": StamenWatercolor,
};
var overlays = {};
var layerscontrol = L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);

function change_legend() {
    layerscontrol.removeFrom(map);
    overlays = {
        'CO2-Emission pro Kopf [t]': worldbankLayer,
    };
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! That works....with: map.removeControl(layerscontrol); and removing the line mentioned...to add a new control, or a changed control I simply made a new function with the normal .addTo() function....that's really great, thank you very much for you help!!!!

Comment: `removeFrom` was renamed to `remove`